# scraping pollution data tables from government website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium

i made this python program to scrape and save the daily maximum pollution values in mexico city, the data will be used in machine learning but i wonder what could be improved:

````
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import bs4
import time
import csv
DRIVER_PATH = r"C:\Users\HP\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.implicitly_wait(60)
for i in range(3):
    try:
        driver.get("http://www.aire.cdmx.gob.mx/default.php?opc=%27aqBjnmU=%27")
        break
    except:
        driver.navigate().refresh()
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="contenedorinformacion03"]/div/iframe')))
airquality=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="sampleform"]/div[1]/div[1]/p[1]/input[2]')
airquality.click()
Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="indice_aire_div"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/span/select')))).select_by_value("2010")
Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="indice_aire_div"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/span/select')))).select_by_value("31")
Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="indice_aire_div"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/span/select')))).select_by_value("12")
Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="indice_aire_div"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]/span/select')))).select_by_value("2021")
carbonmonoxide=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="indice_aire_div"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/span/input[2]')
carbonmonoxide.click()
ozone=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="indice_aire_div"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/span/input[4]')
ozone.click()
zoneclicker=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="indice_aire_div"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/span/input[6]')
zoneclicker.click()
dataclicker=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="indice_aire_div"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[10]/td/span/input[2]')
dataclicker.click()
nextpage=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="indice_aire_div"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[12]/td/div/input')
nextpage.click()
time.sleep(30) #bad internet makes it slow
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features="lxml", parse_only=bs4.SoupStrainer("table"))
table = soup.find("table")
output_rows = []
for table_row in table.findAll('tr'):
    columns = table_row.findAll('td')
    output_row = []
    for column in columns:
        output_row.append(column.text)
    output_rows.append(output_row)
with open('polution.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(output_rows) ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Selenium. Observe that the website sends the following `POST http://www.aire.cdmx.gob.mx/estadisticas-consultas/consultas/resultado_consulta.php` with this request body:

```
-----------------------------40642155113769355341724901495
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tipo_attach"

b
-----------------------------40642155113769355341724901495
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="diai"

31
-----------------------------40642155113769355341724901495
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mesi"

1
-----------------------------40642155113769355341724901495
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="anoi"

2010
-----------------------------40642155113769355341724901495
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="diaf"

12
-----------------------------40642155113769355341724901495
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mesf"

1
-----------------------------40642155113769355341724901495
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="anof"

2021
-----------------------------40642155113769355341724901495
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CO"

on
-----------------------------40642155113769355341724901495
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="O3"

on
-----------------------------40642155113769355341724901495
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="TZ"

on
-----------------------------40642155113769355341724901495
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Q"

maximos
-----------------------------40642155113769355341724901495
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="inter"


-----------------------------40642155113769355341724901495
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="consulta"

Consulta
-----------------------------40642155113769355341724901495
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="trip-start"

2022-08-18
-----------------------------40642155113769355341724901495
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="trip-end"

2022-08-24
-----------------------------40642155113769355341724901495--
```

Use the Requests package to construct such a request dynamically in a function with parameters for the date range, contaminants, zone and output type.

After that, I recommend that you use [pandas.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) to parse the output.

### Suggested

```py
from datetime import date

from requests import Session


def query(
    session: Session,
    start: date, end: date,
    contaminants: tuple[str, ...],
    zones: tuple[str, ...],
    criteria: str,
    # etc. - more params need to be reverse-engineered
) -> str:
    with session.post(
        url='http://www.aire.cdmx.gob.mx/estadisticas-consultas/consultas/resultado_consulta.php',
        data={
            'tipo_attach': 'b',
            'diai': start.day, 'mesi': start.month, 'anoi': start.year,
            'diaf':   end.day, 'mesf':   end.month, 'anof':   end.year,
            'Q': criteria, 'inter': '', 'consulta': 'Consulta',
            **dict.fromkeys(contaminants + zones, 'on'),
        }
    ) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status()
        return resp.text


def main() -> None:
    with Session() as session:
        html = query(
            session, start=date(2010, 1, 1), end=date(2021, 12, 31),
            contaminants=('CO', 'O3'), zones=('TZ',), criteria='maximos',
        )
        print(html)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How did you reverse engineered the parameters? The URL doesn't change, that's why I used selenium instead of requests

Comment: Google "Chrome dev tools"

Comment: The URL not changing is a poor reason to choose Selenium; that's actually even more incentive to use Requests. But if there are parameters, include them in the code. In the real world, things don't change until they do.